# How to split a long article(with formats or images) into pages like Microsoft Word?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my problem:
I'm working on a project on which the customers can post their articles.However,sence the article can be very long,and I need this articles showed on pads(like ipad or surface). So I need to split the article into small pieces and put them into different `.html` files. Each file has a body with style of `width:1024px;height:768px` like ipad2.

I want the artilces splited automatic, like the Microsoft Word. When a line is too high for the current page to contain,it will be put into the next page.
I think it is hard to split it on the server side like PHP, so I tried to finish it in the browser using CSS3 and JS.
I tried tinymce and fckeditor and so on,but the problem is still there.

I need your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: You do know that you can scroll pages in tablets too?

Comment: Actually this time we need to scroll it Left or Right in the ipad,but the IOS developers haven't get a solution.So they give it to us.